# Internationalization of strings with html tags and numbers in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, localization

How to translate a string with tags in between.

Suppose there is a string like

```
$a = 5;
There are <?php echo $a; ?> <span>people</span> in this country.
```

Javascript files:

```
wp_localize_script( 'store-locator', 'storelocatorjstext', array(
    'nostores'   => __( 'There are 5 people in this country.', 'textdomain' )
) );
```

What is the correct way of internationalizing such cases?

My approach:

```
<?php _e('There are 5 <span>people</span> in this country.', 'textdomain'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try below code:**

For Html File:

```
<?php
$a = 5;
echo sprintf( __ ('There are %s <span>people</span> in this country.','textdomain' ), $a);
?>
```

For Javascript File:

```
<?php
$a = 5;
$message = sprintf( __ ('There are %s <span>people</span> in this country.','textdomain' ), $a);
wp_localize_script( 'store-locator', 'storelocatorjstext', array(
    'nostores'   => $message
) );
?>
```

When you get variable in JS:

```
console.log( storelocatorjstext.nostores );
```

Output:

```
There are 5 <span>people</span> in this country.
```

Comment: So is it ok to add html tags while localizing?

Comment: Thanks. In PHP you can mention dynamic variable with %s. But how to do so in Javascript? Please check the updated question for JS code

Comment: Yes you can add html in localizing but this is not a good way to Escaping

Comment: Any idea on including dynamic JS variables?

Comment: Check updated answer. if you got answer mark as answer

Comment: What I really meant is dynamic javascript variable. Since it is off topic here. I created a new question. Please have a look:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088691/internationalization-of-strings-with-javascript-dynamic-variable

Comment: Please do not use "echo sprintf()". Either use printf() or something like  $out = sprintf(); echo $out;

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is the way of writing such strings.

You can add 'return' in place of 'echo' according to your requirement.

```
<?php 
$a = 5;
echo sprintf('There are %s <span>people</span> in this country.', $a); 
?>
```

Comment: So is it ok to add html tags while localizing?

Comment: yeah, try it once.

Comment: You forgot to mention the text domain in your answer. Yes I have tried it. I know it works. But when some one tries to localize, they will see the tags too. So I wondered if there is a way to avoid html tags in localization

Comment: oh sorry, but i just show the way of writing such strings. But according to ypur requirement put your whole tag inside the sprintf.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks

Comment: Do you have idea on how to call dynamic variable with Javascript using wp_localize_script?

Comment: just like this:

Comment: echo sprintf( __( 'There are %s <span>people</span> in this country.', 'textdomain' ), $a);