# Internationalization of strings with JavaScript Dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, wordpress, localization, internationalization

There are two JS strings in my js file.

**JS File Before localization:**

```
var a = 'There are no stores in this area.';
```

**Functions.php**

```
wp_localize_script( 'store-locator', 'storelocatorjstext', array(
    'nostores'   => __( 'There are no stores in this area.', 'storelocator' )
) );
```

I use the above code to localize the script. And then in JS. I write the following

**JS File After localization:**

```
var a = storelocatorjstext.nostores;
```

This works fine. But what if I have a dynamic variable in my JS script? Like following

**JS File Before localization:**

```
var dynamic = 5;
var a = 'There are no stores in this area.';
var b = 'There are '+ dynamic +'stores in this area.';
```

**Functions.php**

```
wp_localize_script( 'store-locator', 'storelocatorjstext', array(
    'nostores'   => __( 'There are no stores in this area.', 'storelocator' ),
    'existingstores'   => __( 'There are 5 stores in this area.', 'storelocator' ) //I know this is wrong. How to add dynamic variable here like we do with PHP sprintf
) );
```

How to internationalize for the string with dynamic variable and how to use it in my JS file? Like we use `sprintf` and `%s` or `%d` in PHP.

**JS File After localization:**

```
var dynamic = 5;
var a = storelocatorjstext.nostores;
var b = ???;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use javascript replace, something like:

php:

```
wp_localize_script( 'store-locator', 'storelocatorjstext', array(
    'nostores'   => __( 'There are no stores in this area.', 'storelocator' ),
    'existingstores'   => __( 'There are %s stores in this area.', 'storelocator' ) //I know this is wrong. How to add dynamic variable here like we do with PHP sprintf
) );
```

js:

```
var dynamic = 5;
var a = storelocatorjstext.nostores;
var b = storelocatorjstext.existingstores.replace("%s", dynamic);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the idea.